# HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#143)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

great site..
i have this error in my program and it happens when i free() i sturct pointer type..
cant seem to understand why .. but i think it has to do with the fact that the pointer is declared globally. 
thank you for your help!

*note that "prev","current" and "head" are global and allocated in another function using malloc();

the code:

```
    void approve_delete(int* delete_request){
    if(*delete_request == 0){
        cout<<" there are no more delet requests\n";
        return;
    }
    char choice[5];
    char ch;

    current = head;
    Prev = head;
    while (current->user.id != MAX_ID ){
        if(current->user.want_delete == true){
            cout<<"name : "<<current->user.name<<" "<<current->user.last_name<<" id:   "<<current->user.id<<endl;
            ch=0;
            while( ch != 'y' && ch != 'Y' && ch != 'n' && ch != 'N') {
                cout<<"approve delete? Y/N  or (Q)exit\n";
                cin.width(5);
                cin>>choice;
                ch=choice[0];
                switch (ch) {
                case 'y':
                case 'Y':
                    item* Temp = current;
                    Prev->next = Prev-> next->next;
                    current=Prev->next;
                    free(Temp);       //here the error occur! 
                    cout<<"in";
                    *delete_request -= 1;
                    cout<<"student deleted\n";
                    break;
                case 'n':
                case 'N':
                    break;
                case 'q':
                case 'Q':
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        Prev = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: yes, its a run time error..and it says something like im trying to write to memory after end of heap buffer..

Comment: So, what was your conclusion?

Comment: You doing `malloc()` or `new` for `current`?

Comment: =] i cant seem to find why or where do i write to that freed memory...

Comment: im doing malloc() for current

Comment: @benmarder, I am also not quite sure what the advantage of `Prev` is in your snippet, can you explain what it's *supposed* to be used for?

Comment: This isn't C but C++ code.

Comment: Do you properly initalise a node's member after having allocated them. Do not rely on `malloc()` returning a reference to `0`ed out memory. Use `calloc()` if you needs this.

Comment: yes : prev points on the node before the "current" node and when i want to delete a node , prev helps me closing the gab by bypassing "current" and then i can free (current);

Comment: @alk im using malloc..

Comment: item* allocate_memory (){
 item* new1 = (item*)malloc(sizeof(item));
 if(new1 == NULL){
  cout<<"Memory error";
  exit(1);
 }
 return new1;
}

Comment: Go through your deletion code, line by line, drawing boxes and lines with pencil on paper.

Comment: I did that :/ maybe i cant free a pointer that allocated globally ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from a different part of the code. After looking at the whole code (I talked to him in private), the problem was caused by a type mismatch.

'item' is a struct that has two boolean members (last to members are of type bool). The function that fills the struct with data is using data from a file. To read from the file, he used fscanf(), and got the data for the boolean members by reading numerical values using "%d%d". Integers occupy more memory than booleans, so the heap got corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the following lines of code and debug it.

```
1. item* Temp = current;
2. Prev->next = Prev-> next->next;
3. current=Prev->next;
4. free(Temp);
```

The first line is defining a pointer `Temp` to a `item` (unknown to us) and initializing it to point to the current `item`. Sure this works.

The second line is assigning the field `next` of `item` that `Prev` points at to be the third `item`. But, what happens to the second `item`? Where did it go? This is a memory leak right here.

The third line assigns `current` to point to the third `item` as descibed above. Still no idea where the second `item` went...

And finally the fourth line frees `Temp`. Sure, nothing wrong with that but I am still confused on where the second `item` went?

You have a memory leak on line 2 of that snippet because you are making it so that nothing points to a `item` and hence you will never be able to free the memory block allocated for that `item`.

Comment: hi jacob, this is a given linked list for this function. the order is : prev - current - other nodes...im trying to delete current..that is why i want prev->next to point on prev->next->next (that exists..) and bypass cuurent ,and then free current (by using temp)

Comment: @benmarder, but that is wrong as I stated in my analysis. Initially both `current` and `Prev` point to the first node (the head). You are then making a backup pointer to point to the head. Then you are saying that the head node should no longer point to the next node (second node), it should point to the next next node (third node). From line 2 you no longer have anything pointing to the second node, a memory leak.

Comment: why not? the second node is current , and temp..

Comment: +1 This analysis is correct. Fixing this will most likely take care of the corruption.

Comment: I'm writing on behalf of YMI because he can't comment here (see his answer further down the page):
@Jacob, you're wrong (anderstandable, as this requires additional knowledge).
The list is a linked list with sentinels (the head and tail are always there, even if the list is empty), so the head and tail should never be deleted. The first iteration of the while loop will never delete the head and will always end up with Prev pointing to current. The while loop stops if current points to the tail. current will never become NULL.

Comment: When finding the node to be deleted, the order is Prev->current->next->next2.
After line 1, the list is: Prev->(Temp = curent)->next->next2.
After line 2, the list is: Prev->next->next2 ; (Temp = current)->next->next2 ; Prev != current.
After line 3, the list is: Prev->(current = next)->next2 ; Temp->(current = next)->next2 ; Temp != current != Prev.
After line 4, the list is: Prev->(next = current)->next2 ; Temp doesn't exist anymore.
Nothing got lost.

Answer (score 0):

At some point before the free, you wrote to memory that wasn't yours.
Maybe you accessed out-of-bounds indices of an array allocated with malloc.
Maybe you accessed memory that you'd already freed.
Whatever the cause, these problems can be hard to debug.

Since you are on Windows, the [pageheap tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/264471) might be helpful, but I haven't used it so I can't help you with it.

Also, Jacob is right about your code being broken if you try to delete the first item.

Answer (score -1):

Most probably, you're 'current' node is null, trying to de-reference a null pointer causes memory exception.

1. Try printing the value in the node, from which u can infer that current object is not null, in which case there is no reason for free(node) not to work.

PS: Always do a 'null' check before u operate on dynamically created objects,
something like

```
             if(temp!=null){
              free(temp);
               }
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Shiva Shankar

Comment: If `current` were a `NULL` pointer then he would not even be able to enter the loop since the right arrow operand would be invalid.

Comment: The C-standard explictly allows a call like: `free(NULL);`.